# Writing from HTML AzureWebApp to CDS

Tags: html, dynamics-crm, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-dynamics, common-data-service

I've got a web application that's being hosted by azurewebsites.net.

I want to take data from a text field / photo captures and store that data in the CDS / Dynamics 365 CE.

I've crafted the website and just need to work on the storing of data now.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [CDS web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/overview) to interact from Azure web app or Azure function or any external platform.

It requires some steps like registering the app in AAD for authentication using clientid/secret, creating service account/application user with privileges in CDS for impersonation from app, etc. it’s explained from top to bottom in [this blog](http://azurefunda.blogspot.com/2018/12/azure-functions-retrieve-data-from.html).